# Word 2010 - Save as PDF with VBA - Keep TOC links?

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

The task has fallen to me to write a macro for Word 2010 that outputs to PDF, using Words **Save As PDF**.

I have the macro saving out to PDF, which iterates down from a selected directory, and exporting all `.doc` files to PDF.

In documents where the Table of Contents was not set up to 'use hyperlinks instead of page numbers', I lose the links in the PDF version of the file.

Essentially, I need to perform the first 4 steps detailed [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2011/03/ensuring-that-word-tocs-create-hyperlinks-in-acrobat/).

Does anyone know how to set this option with VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub AddTOCLinks()
Dim TOC As TableOfContents
With ActiveDocument
  For Each TOC In .TablesOfContents
    With TOC.Range.Fields(1)
      If InStr(.Code.Text, "\h") = 0 Then
        .Code.Text = Trim(.Code.Text) & " \h"
        .Update
      End If
    End With
    TOC.Update
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/2b676845-93fb-4823-9fca-a4a3ad85514f)

Comment: Interestingly, I can see that the changes have been made to the Word document, however the PDF generated still doesn't have working links. If I open the word document and attempt to use the links, they act like regular text (no link!). The 'use hyperlinks' option is set to true however.

Comment: To complete it, I needed to update the TOC, with `TOC.Update` inserted on line 11 above. Thanks